# Ender 5 Underextruding

Tags: ultimaker-cura, hotend, underextrusion

Recently I cleaned up the bowden tube and the nozzle, after that I noticed the 3D was underextruding because the walls of the prints were weak and the first layer didnt adhere on the bed.
I watched some youtube tutorials on how to fix this and pulled the bowden tube until the nozzle, cleaned inside the tube and removed clogs.
My temporary fix is setting the flow on Cura to 200%.

I added a extruder visualizer and it seems to be working just fine.
Any ideas why it is underextruding?
[image]

I'm using PLA at 200C, bed at 60C

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you pulled the Bowden tube out of the hotend and then got this, you almost surely installed it wrong, leaving a gap between the tube and the nozzle for molten filament to fill and jam in. Remove it again with the hotend hot, and if there's a mess inside, look for guides on cleaning it. Then, to reassemble, loosen the fitting from the heat sink by 3/4 to one full turn, press the tube in as far as it will go, then tighten the fitting down to compress the tube against the nozzle.